# How to create a Known Folder or special fodler

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, shared-folders, c#

I'm on creating an application like `DropBox` regarding that I have a requirement of creating a special folder like Favorites, Downloads, Links, Quick access etc. Which can be pinned to the left pane of the file explorer as a separate menu item. This article says that such folders are known as special folders and are having a unique identifier called [`KNOWNFOLDERID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457(v=vs.85).aspx). Is there any possibility to create such folders. Which can be pinned to the left pane as a separate menu, not under Favorites links or user-Profile.

Comment: Yes. You can create shell objects pointing to a real folder. The shell folder can then be pinned to Navigation pane. [Namespace extensions for the Windows Explorer folder pane](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/my-pictures-music-videos-namespace-extensions-for-windows-explorer-folder-pane/) and [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997573.aspx)

Comment: [Add a Custom Folder in Explorer Navigation Pane under "This PC"?](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/add-custom-folder-this-pc-navigation-pane-windows/)

Comment: @w32sh : It is creating under "This pc" as its node, I want to create it as another root like "This PC", like `Dropbox, Google Drive` etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pinning a custom shell folder (as a separate node) can be using `System.IsPinnedtoNameSpaceTree` DWORD setting it to 1. ([Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391662%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396))

Here is another example, [Pin Google Drive to Nav Pane](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/pin-google-drive-navigation-pane/).

Note that `System.IsPinnedtoNameSpaceTree` DWORD works in Windows 10. In earlier versions you use `PinToNameSpaceTree` REG_SZ.

**Windows 8 and higher**

```
HKCR\CLSID\{custom-guid}
```

Set `System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree` DWORD to 1

**Earlier versions of Windows**

```
HKCR\CLSID\{custom-guid}\ShellFolder
```

Create `PinToNameSpaceTree` REG_SZ with blank value data.

Comment: Well, Sounds good. But how do i know the `custom-guid` of my folder? if i choose one, something like `{7D98A6CB-2154-E611-85C7-FFA2AB800CE8}` where do i register it as guid for this folder?

Comment: Use this [link](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/add-custom-folder-this-pc-navigation-pane-windows/) as an example. It's the custom GUID you generate using the GUIDGen.exe tool or via www.guidgen.com.

Comment: But where do i specify this GUID stands for that particular folder?

Comment: In the registry [`TargetFolderPath`](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/pin-google-drive-navigation-pane/) value points to your folder.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what do you mean by "**Is there any possibility to create such folders from my application?**" Are you trying to create **special folders** from your application or inside your application?

However, if you want to create such folders in Windows and also the created folders can be pinned to left pane of the file explorer.

Please visit this [sevenforum](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/18530-user-folder-create-your-own-special-folders.html) link.

Thank you.

Comment: Well now the symbolic link is created under the current user in the left pane. I want to create it as a separate menu

Comment: What you want is to customize the Windows Explorer. Which Windows do not allows. So I'm sorry to say that creating a separate folder like **Dropbox**, **Google Drive** is not possible, or at least still unknown to me, cause that requires by adding values to the **registry** and also the **attributes** too.   You can add folder to **Quick Access**, **network shortcuts** or under current user but nothing else. Please visit this link: [Add Folder by Value](http://www.guidingtech.com/18740/add-folders-programs-windows-explorer-computer/)    Thank you.